# Using command & + disown instead of nohup

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync, nohup

I've tried today to use the `nohup` command to execute an `rsync` command in order to process the copy of some files from a VM to another even if I close the console.

Then I said why not using `rsync [parameters] &` + `disown %1`

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`disown` is the better practice (being built into the shell rather than depending on an external tool), but it requires more work: You need to redirect stdin, stdout, and stderr yourself (whereas `nohup` will do the redirection with a `nohup.out` name hardcoded if you haven't done it yourself).

Thus:

```
rsync "${args[@]}" </dev/null >logfile 2>&1 & disown -h "$!"
```

---

<sub>As a stylistic note, if the only use you make of the PID is passing it to `disown`, I *do* suggest putting the `disown` on the same line as the invocation, as done above: This ensures that the `$!` reference is to the background process forked immediately prior, even if future changes add more code, potentially forking other background processes, after the `rsync` is started. (On the other hand, if you want to refer to the PID later, you might put a variable assignment on the same line: `rsync ... & rsync_pid=$!`, then `disown -h "$rsync_pid"` on a separate line).</sub>